# Ant Design Pagination (Angular)

Tags: angular, pagination, antd

I am now doing cards and pagination using angular version 7 and ant design. I followed ant design website (https://ng.ant.design/components/card/en) for cards but it does not showing how to combine cards and pagination. My question is if i have total 10 cards, and i want to display 5 cards per page. Can anyone should me how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list component combined with cards. The list component supports pagination or infinite scroll, whatever suits you best and it allows various components inside of it.

You will need to add the nzPagination="your_unique_identifier" property to your list and create the template for the pagination like this:

[Here is an official documentation for it](https://ng.ant.design/components/list/en)

**Small example**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'nz-demo-list-grid',
  template: `
    <nz-list [nzDataSource]="data" [nzRenderItem]="item" [nzGrid]="{ gutter: 16, span: 6 }" [nzPagination]="pagination">
      <ng-template #item let-item>
        <nz-list-item [nzContent]="nzContent">
          <ng-template #nzContent>
            <nz-card [nzTitle]="item.title">
              Card content
            </nz-card>
          </ng-template>
        </nz-list-item>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template #pagination>
        <nz-pagination [nzPageIndex]="1" [nzTotal]="50"></nz-pagination>
      </ng-template>
    </nz-list>`
})
export class NzDemoListGridComponent {
  data = [
    {
      title: 'Title 1'
    },
    {
      title: 'Title 2'
    },
    {
      title: 'Title 3'
    },
    {
      title: 'Title 4'
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: The pagination you described does not work as it just shows the pagination component but it does not do the actual pagination as ALL cards are always visible, no matter what page you are on. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjpmet?file=src/app/app.component.ts
I expect only the data of that page to be on screen when the page is selected.